# In Ubuntu, how can I swap the mappings of two keys on my keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, keyboard-layout

I recently bought a new laptop, and I really don't like the positioning of the `Delete` key on its keyboard. Is there any way I can swap the `Delete` key with the `Context Menu` key, or just map both to `Delete`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should swap them:

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym Delete = Menu' -e 'keysym Menu = Delete'
```

Put that line in whatever script is sourced by Ubuntu (or, rather, Gnome) when you log in. (I'm sure there is such a script, just not sure what it is - I'm a KDE user myself)